# Why does object type declaration get error PLS-00103?

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote this as creating an Object but keeps giving me errors PLS-00103:

```
 create or replace  type employee_ty (
  2   emp_num number (10) primary key,
  3   name varchar (15),
  4   address varchar (15)) not final;
  5  /
```

Comment: Can you provide the full error text?  Have you referenced https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you're creating an object but you haven't included the `as object` part of the syntax; you also can't declare an object attribute directly as a primary key:

```
create or replace type employee_ty as object (
  emp_num number (10),
  name varchar (15),
  address varchar (15)
)
not final
/
```

You can then create an object table and declare the primary key as part of that:

```
create table employees of employee_ty (primary key (emp_num));
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4b422fa95548c984ad174013724d60fd) showing constraint violation being thrown.